# Discover source of stdout output

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

I'm using a third party lib that is printing `\n` a couple of hundred times to `stdout` - it appears to be a bug in their logging.

What is the best approach to discover what line of code is producing this output (I'm hoping it's python and not an external library)?

Some ideas:

- How can I change the display of the `\n` character to something recognizable like `A` so that if I step through with a debugger, I can see when the output occurs?
- Can I monkey-patch a low level function to cause some output or a debug-break everytime characters are sent to std-out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to overtake stdout:

```
class StdoutFilter:
    def __init__(self, realStdout):
        self.realStdout = realStdout

    def write(self, text):
        if text == '\n':   # or some more complicated condition
            raise Exception("Newline alert!")

        self.realStdout.write(text)            

import sys
sys.stdout = StdoutFilter(sys.stdout)

# import the 3rd party library and use it
```

In this filter class you can add a counter and raise the exception only after more than *N* subsequent newlines were printed. The stack trace of the exception will reveal the source of the malicious print.

Or you can put a break point there, or change the `\n` to something else.

Comment: Excellent - thankyou. Unfortunately it looks like the library is silently handling all exceptions, or perhaps the call is coming from C code (as pdb.trace() also fails), but this should be more than enough to get me started tracking down the problem.

Comment: For anyone else looking at this: I found `traceback` best for my particular problem `import traceback; traceback.print_stack(file=self.stdout)`